# Problem with encoding after in/out of a database

Tags: html, encoding

I'm doing a bookmarking-system. But when I insert the fetched title "Chapter 4.  Examples for advanced use of VLC's stream output (transcoding, multiple streaming, etc...)", it looks perfectly good in the database, but when I print it out again on the display-page, it looks like this:

`Chapter�4.� Examples for advanced use of VLC's stream output (transcoding, multiple streaming, etc...)`

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

The whole system is running on utf-8.

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Can you dump the raw values of the string to see what those spaces have been encoded as?

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a layer of your application not using utf-8. Try to isolate the problem by inserting known extended characters (e.g.‘’—) into the database and into your application code and see how they are displayed.